# ScrollView and TableVIew both on a Titanium Screen with Normal Scrolling effect

Tags: android, uitableview, titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

I have a Titanium Page, where I am using ScrollView and TableVIew both. But running into a problem -

My ScrollView Portion is about half the page, and I have set Tableview below to it, and when I scroll on Scrollview nothing scrolls up (as it is only half the screen), but when I scroll the TableView, then only tableview gets scrolled and that too in that below portion only. And the above (scrollview portion remains static in its position)

My code is:

```
<Alloy>
<Window id="main_window" title="Profile" navTintColor="white" backgroundColor="white" barImage="/images/NavBackground.png" orientationModes="Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT">
    <ScrollView id="scrollable_view" scrollType="vertical" top="0dp" height="89%" contentWidth="100%">
    </ScrollView>
    <TableView id='list_rows' top="auto" height="100%" separatorColor="#CCCCCC" >
    </TableView>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

I have also tried inserting the TableView in Scrollview and setting-up top parameter of tableview to auto and 400dp (in my case).

Comment: Scroll view only shows the scrolling effects when the content inside the scrollview are larger. Could you please let us know What exactly you want to implement?

Comment: What is the exact behavior that you need? And what are the elements that you will add to the scrollview? Do you want the scrollview to take for example half of the screen, and the tableview takes the other half? Which means that what will scroll depends on whether the user is scrolling the first or the second half. Please explain the required user interface so I can help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `TableView` into the `ScrollView` and disable the scroll functionality of the `TableView`.